# scala.io.Source.fromInputStream does not throw the MalformedInputException further

Tags: scala, java-io

I have the following scala code which takes a String, messes up with the UTF-8 characters and then tries to read it via Source.fromInputStream:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8

import scala.io.Source

val stringSourceAsBytes = "hellö wörld".getBytes(UTF_8)

val messedUpUTF8 = 128.toByte +: stringSourceAsBytes

val linesIterator : Iterator[String] =
try {
  val input = new ByteArrayInputStream(messedUpUTF8)
  Source.fromInputStream(input).getLines()
}catch{
  case exc: Throwable => println(" This is an exception !")
  Iterator()
}

linesIterator.mkString("\n")
```

Shouldn't I see the "This is an exception !" message ? Because I don't see it. 
Indeed I get a printed stack trace, but I cannot catch the exception and treat it properly ...

BTW: my console shows:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(IO.sc:277)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(IO.sc:335)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(IO.sc:174)
   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(IO.sc:181)
   at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(IO.sc:157)
   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(IO.sc:322)
   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(IO.sc:388)
   at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(IO.sc:66)
   at scala.collection.Iterator.toString(IO.sc:1409)
   at scala.collection.Iterator.toString$(IO.sc:1409)
   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toString(IO.sc:1413)
   at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(IO.sc:53)
```

Comment: I'm currently using scala 2.12

Comment: Don't try to cram wall of code into comments, comments do not support it properly! Use the little gray 'edit' button to update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two funny things happen here at once:

- a classic error with lazy iterators and `try-catch`-blocks
- weird behavior of the REPL that blows itself up while trying to be user friendly.

You don't see the `"This is an exception !"`-message, because instantiating the lazy iterator doesn't attempt to read a single byte from the stream. This `try-catch` block succeeds and happily returns the ticking time-bomb, the actual error happens later, outside of the `try-catch`.

However, if you force the iterator to get all the bytes, for example by appending `.mkString`:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8

import scala.io.Source

val stringSourceAsBytes = "hellö wörld".getBytes(UTF_8)
val messedUpUTF8 = 128.toByte +: stringSourceAsBytes

val streamContent =
try {
  val input = new ByteArrayInputStream(messedUpUTF8)
  Source.fromInputStream(input).getLines().mkString("\n")
}catch{
  case exc: Throwable => println(" This is an exception !")
}
```

then you get the output:

```
 This is an exception !
```

as expected. Your stack trace seems to come from elsewhere, check the exact line numbers again.

---

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION EDIT**

To see the `" This is an exception !"` message in your updated code, you would have to catch where the exception is thrown, not where the lazy iterator is defined:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream 
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8 
import scala.io.Source 

val stringSourceAsBytes = "hellö wörld".getBytes(UTF_8) 
val messedUpUTF8 = 128.toByte +: stringSourceAsBytes

// building the exception-bomb is harmless
val linesIterator: Iterator[String] = { 
  val input = new ByteArrayInputStream(messedUpUTF8) 
  Source.fromInputStream(input).getLines() 
} 


val combinedLines: String = try {
  // detonating the exception-bomb should be surrounded by try-catch
  linesIterator.mkString("\n")
} catch { 
  case exc: Throwable => {
    println(" This is an exception !") 
    ""
  }
}
```

This again prints `This is an exception !` and sets `combinedLines` to empty string.

---

**EDIT-2: The REPL**

If you for some reason insist on running it in repl, then you cannot let the "poisoned" iterator escape into scope, because the Repl cannot deal with it for some reason, and blows itself up.

This here works in the repl, but this is essentially the same as the first solution:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream 
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8 
import scala.io.Source 

val stringSourceAsBytes = "hellö wörld".getBytes(UTF_8) 
val messedUpUTF8 = 128.toByte +: stringSourceAsBytes 

val combinedLines: String = try {
  val linesIterator: Iterator[String] = { 
    val input = new ByteArrayInputStream(messedUpUTF8) 
    Source.fromInputStream(input).getLines() 
  } 
  linesIterator.mkString("\n")
} catch { 
  case exc: Throwable => {
    println(" This is an exception !") 
    ""
  }
}
```

The REPL cannot deal with iterators that are just about to throw exceptions. The reason is that it calls the `hasNext` on the iterator (it prints the `non-empty iterator` description for valid iterators, so it has to call `hasNext` once). But your stream throws an exception when `hasNext` is invoked, as the following snippet shows:

```
scala> val it = try { 
  Source.fromInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(messedUpUTF8)).getLines().hasNext 
} catch { case t: Throwable => 
  println("yes, hasNext blows up the REPL")  
}
```

results in:

```
yes, hasNext blows up the REPL
```

Run it as script (or maybe try paste-mode), then it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey for your kind answer, please check my edit on the original post and run the code in a scala REPL.

Comment: @humbletrader the comment ends with a comma? Did you want to ask for some clarification after the comma? Ah, see the edit now.

Comment: I modified the code so that mkString is called outside of the try-catch block .... and still I see the MalformedInputException printed and I don't get the "This is an exception" message

Comment: @humbletrader Look at the second part of the updated answer. Reload the page eventually. It is thrown when `mkString` is called, not when the iterator is created.

Comment: I must be crazy, It still does not work for me ...I copy-pasted and even re-started the IDE  .. no luck !

Comment: @humbletrader wait, you said something about the repl? Why are you trying to run something that long from the repl... Anyway: yes, I can confirm, the repl blows up the iterator for some reason, once the `linesIterator` is added to scope. I've updated the question again. I don't think there is a way not to blow up the iterator once it is given to the repl.

Comment: I see now, it was the REPL ... pfuuuh ...this is nasty. Anyway, is there a way to avoid passing the "exception bomb" to the users of my function ( I'm actually working with huge data Iterators and there's no way I can consume them on the spot) ?  ... moreover, If I don't document this behavior, the users of my Iterator won't have any clue about the need to try-catch ...

Comment: @humbletrader Well, documenting it would be the first line of defence... If you want, you can wrap the iterator into some "exception-bomb-disposal-expert"-class that knows how to deal with garbage input. Hard to tell without much more information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I will post another question on SO about the last question. It's more related to apache spark, as spark seems to be the consumer of my Iterator so I have no power to handle the exception. Once again, thank you !